# Proving that height of this triangle is also height of pyramid

Tags: geometry, triangles, solid-geometry

[image: Drawing of the pyramid]

We have pyramid MABC, where BC=x, AM=y, and AB=AC=MB=MC=z. MK is height in triangle CMB, and AK is height in triangle ABC. They will both cross the point K, because they share base CB and they are both isosceles triangle, legs being equal to *z* and for the same reason AK=MK. MO is height in a triangle AKM, but how do we know that MO is also the height of the pyramid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $BC$ is orthogonal to plane $AMK$ because it's orthogonal to two lines in $AMK$: $MK$ and $AK$. Let's draw a line in plane $ABC$ thru point $O$ parallel to $BC$, it will also be perpendicular to plane $AMK$ and perpendicular to $MO$. Now we have that $MO$ is perpendicular to two intersecting lines in plane $ABC$ (the other one is $AK$) and thus it's perpendicular to the plane. Done.

Comment: What's the difference from my solution, note that I didn't give all the detail in order to let some work to the asker! Anyway that's fine.

Comment: @gimusi: I did not see details of your answer when I was typing. I agree that showing that $BC$ is orthogonal to $AMK$ is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Simply note that MO is orthogonal to $\triangle ABC$ thus by definition it is the height of the pyramid.

Comment: To be sure that MO is orthogonal to △ABC, we need another line other than AK which will make a right angle with MO.

Comment: It is true for symmetry, indeed it is orthogonal also to BC.

Comment: How can MO be orthogonal to BC, can you clarify a little bit more?

Comment: The plane AKM is a plane of symmetry orthogonal to BC, thus MO (contained in this plane) is also orthogonal to BC.